# PosControlException: Failed to set property MarqueeType

Tags: c#, opos, pos-for-.net

I am trying to Scroll a text in my pole display. My pole display model is **CD7220** 
But I am getting a PosControlException message "Failed to set property MarqueeType."

here is the code i use

```
LineDisplay lineDisplay;
        PosExplorer explorer;
        try
        {

            explorer = new PosExplorer();
            DeviceCollection devColl = explorer.GetDevices(DeviceType.LineDisplay);
            if (devColl == null || devColl.Count <= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Device not found");
                return;
            }

            DeviceInfo device = explorer.GetDevice("LineDisplay", "CD7220");
            lineDisplay = (LineDisplay)explorer.CreateInstance(device);
             lineDisplay.Open();

            lineDisplay.Claim(1000);

            lineDisplay.DeviceEnabled = true;


            string s = "Welcome to ovelco food city!";
            int wWindth = s.Length + 20;

            lineDisplay.CreateWindow(0, 0, 1, 20, 1, wWindth);
            lineDisplay.DisplayText(s);
            lineDisplay.MarqueeType = DisplayMarqueeType.Left;
            lineDisplay.MarqueeUnitWait = 200; 
            lineDisplay.MarqueeFormat = DisplayMarqueeFormat.Walk;

            Console.ReadKey();
            lineDisplay.ClearText();
            lineDisplay.Release();
            lineDisplay.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //  MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```

how to fix this issue and scroll a text in pole display perfectly ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to Unified POS docs, you will get an error setting the MarqueeType property to "left" unless the CapHMarquee property is true, (and your window width is greater than your columns, which it is).  Write a test to show the value of CapHMarquee; perhaps your particular device doesn't support it?